# Best practices method to expose / retreive GTM debug mode using JS Outside of GTM?

Tags: debugging, google-tag-manager

Is there a best practices method for using JS from the CMS or Chrome devtools to determine if the GTM container associated with a given page is in debug_mode?

Attempted to retrieve from the dataLayer array (neither debug_mode or _dbg is present), and to use the 'google_tag_manager['G-xxxxxxxxxx'].dataLayer.get method. Both without success.

It can be seen when sniffing the network traffic, but I am looking for a method that exposes it as a global variable, ideally without using a custom JS variable within GTM to set / push, as to do so is not best practices.

Comment: Untested, hence a comment, but the global "google_tag_manager" object set up by GTM seems to acquire an additional property "debugGroupId" in debug mode.  The GTM object also has a getter for your specific instance, but that can access apparently only dataLayer variables, and not built-ins such as container version (which is always QUICK_PREVIEW in preview mode). I think setting up a tag that sets a variable only in preview mode (using container version in your trigger) is more reliable and might not be such a bad practice after all.